# How to use both -moz- and -webkit- css property to support different browsers?

Tags: css

For all CSS3 properties I have to use different vendor prefixed versions to support different Render Engines. Here is an example:

```
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;

background:#dee0e1;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f1f2f3), to(#dee0e1));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(#f1f2f3, #dee0e1);
background:-o-linear-gradient(#f1f2f3, #dee0e1);
background:linear-gradient(#f1f2f3, #dee0e1);
```

For a border-radius I have to use 3 different properties and for a background gradient I have to use background property in 5 different way. It increase the size of CSS.

Is there a way to use only one property and make Firefox 1-5 understand it?

Comment: Further reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/03/css_vendor_pref.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`LESS`**](http://lesscss.org/) is a CSS language that compiles to normal CSS and gives you the ability to abstract away a lot of the tedious elements of writing stylesheets such as typing multiple vendor prefixes every time.

Here's a decent tutorial on making the vendor prefix problem less painful:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-never-type-a-vendor-prefix-again/

> You know the drill quite well. Want to
>   give some section of your website
>   rounded corners with CSS3? Then you’ll
>   require nothing short of three vendor
>   prefixes: webkit, moz, and the W3C
>   recommended form. Isn’t that a huge
>   waste of time — not to mention screen
>   space? What if, instead, we could use
>   a class file? Well, we can! I’ll show
>   you how today.

.. and here are the LESS classes from the tutorial: http://snipplr.com/view/47181/less-classes/

Comment: Fantastic. It seems very sold solution. I'm just wondering, is it supported in older browser, say IE 7 or FF 3.0? I mean the structure itself, not CSS3 features!

Comment: LESS just compiles to normal CSS, so it doesn't add any extra cross-browser compatibility issues (just solves some in this case!). I assume that less.js (for in browser compilation) has good cross-browser compatibility, wikipedia states "(Internet Explorer 6+, WebKit, Firefox)".

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to use only one
>   property and make Firefox 1-5
>   understand it?

In short, no.

Firefox before version 4 requires `-moz-border-radius`: http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Firefox 3.6 [still has some market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201006-201106), so you should keep the vendor prefixed version for now.

> for a background gradient I have to
>   use background property in 5 different
>   way. It increase the size of CSS.

There's nothing you can do about this, at the moment.

Eventually, all browsers will support `linear-gradient`. Until that happens, *and* the older versions are no longer used, you'll have to put up with bloated CSS.

The gradient code actually gets worse if you want to support as many browsers as possible:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```
background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
```

Comment: Thank for explanation. By the way how can I know what is -moz-, -webkit-, -o-, -ms-, etc for other selectors, say box-shadow? Is there a reference for each of this render engines? Or better is there a complete reference which list all them altohether?

Comment: Try [http://caniuse.com/](http://caniuse.com/) or Google for example "box-shadow mdc", and follow the Mozilla link + look at the "browser compatibility" section: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, vendor prefixed CSS simply does not affect the projects here that much 
as the problem was for the most part eliminated with a javascript closure to hold the cached results of on-the-fly prefix testing and but a few lines of javascript. This was implemented long  before they started going nuts with prefixes.

Basically the tried and true technique which is today used by libraries such as modernizer and such relies on a browser behavior that is oddly pretty consistent across all browser, and with minor variations can be used for all sorts of feature detection.

lets take for example the css property 'transform'. If you test the result of...

```
somediv.style['transform']
```

... and the browser supports that name , you'll get back a string , even if it's empty for the property not being set. If on the other hand the browser does not recognize that name it will return the javascript undefined.result instead.

Since there really is a fairly finite number of vendor prefixes such as....

```
(Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit Web-Kit)
```

...it does not take much to test them, and if you cache the result of the test it can be blazingly fast. with the libraries here , we are actually able to author using the plain old standards based names and not worry about it save for those odd ones where the property value is laid out differently such as in some gradients.

With that caching though it's so fast that it translates all the CSS in the CSS files and STYLE elements even before the DOMContentLoaded event is reached so there is not even any screen flashing or other oddities one might see in scripts that have to wait for load events

While the testing and caching is occurring during load , all the various CamelCase Hyphen-Case formatting of those property names is taken care of as well, so that even later while coding or when the attributes are being handed programmatically like for CSS 3D, or on occasion even more CSS is loaded , all the figuring has already been done.

There are also some other neat things that can be done too , such as augmenting a browser's CSS support to some extent , as well as one thing I've been tinkering with that will actually 
allow jQuery-ui .css files to actually fully validate and at he same time be able to ditch most of their images without loosing one lick of the appearance.

BTW , besides the technique being ridiculously easy , and blazingly fast , the work itself happens at the second stage of document.readyState , long before the page is even fully loaded or even to document.readyState 4 "complete".

CSS may not be the friend of a lot of programmers , but we love it , and have even got it so that CSS is what loads and configures those third party plugins from folks like jQuery , eliminating the need for most of them little initialization bits of scripting and in many cases eliminating all of it.

Sometimes the shear volume of silliness out there has folks thinking the idea of being able to have validated content and clean source has went the way of clean air, but not really as it's nut much harder than taking a CSS border triangle trick and updating it to have textures to make egyption pyramids :)